# Find specific element index from Tensor(Matrix)

Tags: pytorch

I am a student just beginning to study deep learning.

```
   x_norm = (x**2).sum(1).view(-1, 1)
   if y is not None:
       y_norm = (y**2).sum(1).view(1, -1)
   else:
       y = x
       y_norm = x_norm.view(1, -1)
   ## NOTICE ##
   dist = torch.exp(-1*(x_norm + y_norm - 2.0 * torch.mm(x, torch.transpose(y, 0, 1))))
   return dist

dist = pairwise_distances(atom_s[:3,-3:])
zero_mat=torch.zeros_like(dist,dtype=torch.float)
dist= torch.where(dist>exp(-8),dist,zero_mat)
```

Above is my coding to make pairwise distance map. And change some element that satiesfy a condition to 0.

Question is that "how can I get indexes of elements that satiesfy specific condition ( e.g larger than >0.5)?? without using slow 'for' loop.

Comment: please print tensor from which you want to find index...or if it is normal tensor you can do `>>> (dist > 0.5).nonzero()` which will return indexes of all elements that are more than `0.5`

Comment: Latter one is exactly what I want. Thank you so much, have a good day!

Comment: glad it help i have made it answer. In case comment will deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is normal tensor you can use [`torch.nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.nonzero)

```py
>>> (dist > 0.5).nonzero()
```

which will return indices of all elements that are more than `0.5`

**Example:**

```py
>>> dist = torch.rand((6,5))
>>> dist
tensor([[0.7549, 0.0962, 0.3198, 0.6868, 0.8117],
        [0.0785, 0.7666, 0.2623, 0.5140, 0.2713],
        [0.5768, 0.8160, 0.8654, 0.6978, 0.0138],
        [0.8147, 0.1394, 0.3204, 0.0104, 0.2872],
        [0.1396, 0.5639, 0.7085, 0.7151, 0.8253],
        [0.6115, 0.0214, 0.6033, 0.1403, 0.1977]])

>>> (dist > 0.5).nonzero()
tensor([[0, 0],
        [0, 3],
        [0, 4],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 2],
        [4, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 0],
        [5, 2]])
```